# manifest.json issue: dictionary keys must be quoted

Tags: json, google-chrome, dictionary, google-chrome-extension, manifest

```
{
  "name": "Supreme Bot",
  "description": "Automate the checkout process for supremenewyork.com!",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.supreme.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "supreme.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon" : "icon-16.png",
    "default_title": "Enable/Disable"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon-16.png"

  },
    { //this line is showing up as an error that says manifest is not valid json
//dictionary keys must be quoted
  "name": "Supreme Bot",
  ...
  "options_page": "options.html",
  ...
    }
}
```

I am working on an autofill and auto-checkout bot for buying clothing. I am trying to add an options page so that I will be able to adjust sizes (code for that is in a different file). Line 25 column 6 says that there is a syntax error where dictionary keys must be quoted. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have a spare `{` before the line that is causing a problem?  And why are you repeating `"name": "Supreme Bot"`?

Comment: Well, as the error states, it is a syntax error. You clearly need to not have that `{` there. The structure of the file is using JSON to represent an Object. This means there are `"key": "Value"` pairs.  A bare Object is not permitted.  Yo have duplicated the `"name": "Supreme Bot",` and left a lot of `...` which doesn't give us any hint why you think that doing this is correct. Please provide the entire file, and why you are tacking on this extra part in `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [JSON sample here](https://github.com/orbitbot/chrome-extensions-examples/blob/master/analytics/manifest.json), that part after the comma should be followed by a "key" not a new pair of curly brackets. Try removing it so your JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Supreme Bot",
  "description": "Automate the checkout process for supremenewyork.com!",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.supreme.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "supreme.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon" : "icon-16.png",
    "default_title": "Enable/Disable"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon-16.png"

  },

  "name": "Supreme Bot",
  "options_page": "options.html", 
}
```